# Can you install the PR2 robot on ROS Indigo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you install the PR2 robot simulator on ROS Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227208/can-you-install-the-pr2-robot-on-ros-indigo?/) by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. The [pr2_simulator wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator) lists it as released for Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on 2016-02-21**:
Do you know where the instructions for installing the pr2 on indigo are?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-21**:
It looks like the documentation hasn't been updated in a while, and the pr2-desktop package hasn't been released for Indigo yet. Have you tried installing the pr2-simulator package from debs: `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-simulator` ?